# error: Error: Unable to resolve module `@react-native-community/art` from `node_modules/react-native-pie/src/Pie.js`

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting an error when I am running my application:

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module `@react-native-community/art` from `node_modules/react-native-pie/src/Pie.js`: @react-native-community/art could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/mayankbudhiraja/Desktop/appcorona/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:186:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/mayankbudhiraja/Desktop/appcorona/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/mayankbudhiraja/Desktop/appcorona/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/mayankbudhiraja/Desktop/appcorona/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:267:42)
    at /Users/mayankbudhiraja/Desktop/appcorona/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:434:31
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/mayankbudhiraja/Desktop/appcorona/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:431:18)
    at /Users/mayankbudhiraja/Desktop/appcorona/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/mayankbudhiraja/Desktop/appcorona/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
```

What I did to correct the error?

1. I tried running the above mentioned steps (didn't worked)
2. Tried reinstalling the Pie Chart (didn't worked)
3. Deleted entire node_modules (didn't worked)

Can you please help me with the issue?

Comment: Same issiue... Did you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

For react-native-pie >= 1.1.0 install peer dependency

## NPM

npm i --save @react-native-community/art
OR

## Yarn

yarn add @react-native-community/art